# Модальное окно не закрывается на мобильных устройствах. В чем может быть причина?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

При просмотре сайта на телефоне (iPhone 4s) или планшете (iPad 4), если открываю модальное окно, то не могу нажать крестик, чтобы его закрыть. Просматривал в Safari, Opera Mini, Chrome. Ничего не происходит. На ноутбуке все работает. Сталкиваюсь с таким впервые, даже не представляю, как диагностировать проблему.

[Демо](http://goo.gl/9UFAo9) — (модальное окно открывается кликом по картинке или заголовку новости)

Здесь код скрипта, отвечающего за модальное окно. Сразу оговорюсь, что я не знаю JS, использую готовые скрипты, потому и прошу помощи.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.click-modal').click(function(e){ // Что будет происходить  по клику по ссылке

            var post_id = $(e.target).parent().attr('id');

            jQuery.ajax({
                url : posttest.ajax_url,
                type : 'post',
                data : {
                    action : 'post_test_it',
                    post_id : post_id
                },
                success : function( response ) {

                    //alert(response)        

                    result_arr = eval( response );
                    $('.modalWindow').html('<div class="modalWindow_ContentWrapper"><div class="container clean-cornes clean-borders block-margins-top block-margins-bottom MainContent"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-close"></i><div class="row"><h1 class="clean-margins-top">' + result_arr[1] + '</h1></div><div class="row block-margins-top-15"><div class="col-md-4">' + result_arr[0] + '</div><div class="col-md-8"><p>' + result_arr[2] + '</p></div></div></div></div>' ); 

//'class' => 'col-md-12 clean-paddings img-responsive'                  

                    $('.modalWindow img').addClass('col-md-12 clean-paddings img-responsive');
                    $('.modalWindow').fadeIn('fast');
                }
            });




        });
});

jQuery(function($){
        $(document).mouseup(function (e){ // событие клика по веб-документу
            var div = $(".modalWindow"); // тут указываем класс элемента
                if (!div.is(e.target) && div.has(e.target).length === 0) { // если клик был не по нашему блоку, и не по его дочерним элементам
                    div.fadeOut('slow'); // скрываем его
                    //div.html(''); // очистка
                    }
                else 
                {
                    var div1 = $(".fa-close"); // тут указываем класс элемента
                        if ( div1.is(e.target) ) { div.fadeOut('slow'); } // скрываем его
                }

        });
});
```

Comment: если не работает на мобильном гаджете, то, вероятно, дело в том, что с ноутбука вы создаете событие click, а с телефона touch - возможно, ваше окно блокирует тач-события

Comment: Было бы нелишним уточнить на какой модели телефона и в каком браузере не работает.

Comment: @lexxl — спасибо за наводку, действительно не подумал об этом. А как проверить это?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась с помощью [этой темы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135736/does-jquery-mouseup-event-work-on-touch-devices).

Было:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e){ // событие клика по веб-документу
```

Стало:

```
$(document).bind( "mouseup touchend", function (e){ // событие клика по веб-документу
```

Модальное окно стало закрываться на мобильных устройствах.